# Python, PIL, ImageFont, Line Break, aalib and text module

Tags: python, line, python-imaging-library, break

I am trying to save my text output from aalib to an image file using the text method.  It does not seem to know what the line breaks/ new lines means.  It makes everything one long line.  It renders the line breaks/ new lines with a question mark embedded within a box.

```
screen = aalib.AsciiScreen(width=81, height=33 )
myimage= Image.open(videofilename).convert("L").resize(screen.virtual_size)
screen.put_image((0,0), myimage)


font = ImageFont.truetype("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeMonoBold.ttf",15)
img=Image.new("RGBA", (1000,700),(120,20,20))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0, 0),screen.render(),(255,255,0),font=font)
img.save("a_test.png", "PNG")
img.show()
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate question.  I am using "screen.render()" to generate a ascii text of an image.  And the text method does not know how to read the line break.

Comment: `aalib.AsciiScreen.render()` simply returns a newline `\n` delimited string. You're still calling `ImageDraw.Draw.text()` to draw the final text image which is exactly the same issue from the linked post.

Comment: Also, why are you assigning to `draw` twice? That would seem to overwrite your previous `ImageDraw.Draw` object defeating the purpose of adding text.

Comment: "draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)" that was left over from testing.  I will edit in the post.  "aalib.AsciiScreen.render() simply returns a newline \n delimited string." that it does.  But when I try to place the text on top of my image it does not have any newlines in it.

Comment: Newline `\n` is a special character that the `text()` call doesn't know how to output in the image. You need to split the results of `aalib.AsciiScreen.render()` into individual lines and add them into the image using a separate `text()` call for each line (adjusting the vertical position appropriately). See the link in the first comment for how to do that.